# Port declarations without direction error

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, boolean-expression

In my behavioral model I keep getting this error in the file. Am I doing this correctly in Verilog?  I'm getting:

> Port declarations without direction are only supported in System
>   Verilog. You must compile with the -sverilog flag to enable support
>   for this feature.

```
module NSG_function
(
        input x, [1:0] q, // current_state,
        output [1:0] d // next_state
);

assign d[1] = ~x&q[0]&q[1] | x&~q[0]&q[1] | x&q[0]&~q[1];
assign d[0] = ~x | ~q[0]&q[1];

endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the input `q`.
Though you put it on the same line as `input x,`, since you declare q as an array, it needs its own input declaration.

```
module NSG_function
(
        input x, 
        input [1:0] q, // current_state
        output [1:0] d // next_state
);

assign d[1] = ~x&q[0]&q[1] | x&~q[0]&q[1] | x&q[0]&~q[1];
assign d[0] = ~x | ~q[0]&q[1];

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to specify `input` for each signal:

```
input x, 
input [1:0] q, // current_state,
```